# Is the system of connectives $\{\lnot, \leftrightarrow\}$ complete?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If we consider the system$ \{\lnot, \leftrightarrow\}$ can we express all the connectives like $\wedge$, $\vee$ or $\rightarrow$ just by using $\lnot$ and $\leftrightarrow$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Maman I don't really know what "because of truth table" means here, but yes: it is the case that you **cannot** express $\vee$ (or $\wedge$ or $\implies$) using just $\neg$ and $\iff$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber "by truth table" just means that we give value ($0$ or $1$) to the variables and compare formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With two variables $a,b$, anything you can construct with $\neg$ and $\leftrightarrow$ is true in an even number of the four possible cases. This follows by structural induction.
As a consequence, you cannot obtain $a\land b$.

Comment: Is it because in all  cases we will have different truth table ? Also what do you mean by "structural induction" ? I f we increase the number of variables ?

Comment: @Maman No, "structural induction" means "increasing the number of times we apply either $\lnot$ or $\leftrightarrow$". Note that this requires strong induction, if that's a distinction you make.